# Google App Engine import libraries from parent folder

Tags: google-app-engine, python-import, google-app-engine-python

So my directory structure looks something like this:

```
\Project-Dir\
|- lib\
|  |- flask\
|  |- ...
|- module1_dir\
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- app.yaml
|  |- app.py
|  |- ...
|- module2_dir\
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- app.yaml
|  |- app.py
|  |- ...
|- ...
```

Inside `app.py`

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../lib')))
```

I have two modules inside the same root directory. They are both deployed to App Engine together. They also share the same libraries. The libraries are all pretty beefy so I'm trying to place them in a shared directory (lib).

I'm running `dev_appserver.py` from `\Project-Dir\` and passing the two .yamls. My `sys.path` is set up fine to include the `lib\` directory. And yet the sandbox seems to stubbornly insist that the libraries in `lib\` *just don't exist.*

I'm sure I'm just missing something small like a config change somewhere. Or does App Engine really just flat-out not support such a setup?

EDIT: The imports work fine when I run it outside of `dev_appserver.py`.

Comment: Do you create a `__init__.py` in your python package? Or please show your  total directory.

Comment: And how are you setting up your `sys.path`, too many times i've seen that it's just flat-out wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I spoke to a Google support engineer, after facing the same problem. Unfortunately, GAE does not support this kind of setup.

When you use the Modules API, module 1 and module 2 run inside separate Python virtual environments as separate self-contained instances. They cannot 'see' the contents of their parent directory. Modifying sys.path doesn't make a difference.

There are two solutions:

(a) Duplicate your 'lib' folder by placing it inside both 'module1_dir' and 'module2_dir'.

(b) Place the module files directly in the root directory.